# Load a few thumbnails with one HTTP request

Tags: javascript, web, client-side

Suppose I display a few dozens thumbnails in a few web pages (10 thumbnails per page). I would like to load them as quickly as possible.

Does it make sense to get a few thumbnails with one HTTP request (one thumbnail is ~10K) ? How would you suggest do it with JavaScript?

Comment: You want to get back 10 separate files (images) with 1 request?

Comment: Yes. I can merge them in server-side on the fly, for instance. Otherwise, I can merge them off-line and store in a single file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding network performance it does really make sense. 
You could, for example, put a predefinited number of thumbails along in a single image.

On client side you can treat that image like using "css sprite" tecnique
(http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_sprites.asp)

Answer (score 3):

You can, but you need to jump through a few hoops:

1) Base-64 encode the images on the server as a single file.

2) Send them to the client as a single request blob, via AJAX.

3) Decode the images back into pieces.

4) Use Data-URIs to insert them into the DOM.

...not really worth it.

Answer (score 1):

If it's important for you to send the images as fast as possible I would consider sending them as a sprite. Unfortunately this may be somewhat difficult on the back end if the provided images may vary. If they are static and the same for every user it is way easier as you can manually prepare the images and the front end code to display the correct image parts.

In combination with the sprite approach it would also be useful to enable progressive/interlaced loading in order to deliver visible results as fast as possible.